# JSX element 'router' has no corresponding closing tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Getting the following error -

> JSX element 'Router' has no corresponding closing tag.

for this code -

```
<Router>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <Sidebar />
    < Header />
    <Content>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <ImportCode />
      < /Content>
      < Footer > I'm a 30px tall footer</Footer>
      < /div>
        < /Router >
```

Answer (score 0):

Error goes away the extra space in the closing tag is removed -

```
<Router>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <Sidebar />
    < Header />
    <Content>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <ImportCode />
    </Content>
    <Footer> I'm a 30px tall footer</Footer>
  </div>
</Router>
```